# textures in tilemap games: use 2d planes or 3d objects? (example with Dragons of Atlantis)

Tags: unity, textures, tilemap

How to create the textures in games such as Dragons of Atlantis?

I was thinking about 2 ways:

- using 2d planes to save space and memory, using the color from the 3d
  software
- adding a very simple mesh and stick a detailed texture onto it in Unity

Is there a preferable way to choose between the two?
The first solution could save some memory, but maybe a bit difficult to change the camera view for example at the end of the game.
As for the second solution, it would be creating a very detailed mesh in the 3d software, paint the texture, cut the texture and add it to a very simple mesh, such as cubes. Could be better, but maybe it would take more work.

What do you think?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's a 2D isometric tilemap with pre-rendered tiles.

Some or actually most structures are larger than a single tile, sometimes spanning large areas, one looks like 5x5 tilea, another looks like an arbitrary shape but still isometric on its outline to hide the fact that it's a flat 2D isometric tilemap composed of individual sprites/textures.

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not sure whether this will fully answer your question, I want to point you to a [tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpB4BApnKhM&list=SPbghT7MmckI4qGA0Wm_TZS8LVrqS47I9R) that might be very helpful to you if you want to make some kind of tilemap. The guy in the video first explains the "wrong" way (have each tile be a plane) and why exactly it's "wrong", then he goes on to explain what the "right" way and showing how he would implement it. The series in total is a bit long (~5 hours), but you'll probably be able to skip some parts where he might be explaining things you might already know.

Comment: Thanks Lokkij, I already watched this tutorial, but I agree with you it was a very good one. ;)